# How convert a string into a ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, date

I need to update a field (called `updated_at`). The field in MySQL is of type `datetime`, and the class is `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. But the dates are *strings* like `"10/17/2008"`. I used `"10/17/2008".to_date` (And I intend `.to_time` and `.to_datetime`), and even if in console the ActiveRecord class save successfully, the field in the database still is the current date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK.. let's take them one at the time.

First, it is not recommended to set a field name `updated_at`, since this is a "magic" field that is automatically populated by Rails.

If you want to disable this functionality, you may:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.record_timestamps = false
end
```

in your class, but this will also disable `created_at` fields.

The best option is to add a new field (e.g. `my_updated_at`) as date in the database, and then Rails will automatically handle conversions, meaning that the next snippet will work:

```
Foo.new({:my_updated_at => "10/17/2008"})
```

Second, the answer on how to parse a string to `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` is:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['UTC'].parse("10/17/2008")
```

but I don't think this will help you (of course, change `UTC` with your current date/time).

Comment: I tried this at the Rails console `2.0.0p247 :001 > ActiveSupport::TimeZone['UTC'].parse("10/17/2008")` and got `ArgumentError: argument out of range` - did it really work for you? I am using `Rails 4.0.4`.

Comment: Same here. I get argument out of range. I'm using Rails 4.0.5.

Comment: I think you are seeing the "argument out of range" error because of the format of the sample date provided. Try for example using "2008-10-17" instead of "10/17/2008".

Answer (score 4):

Simply

```rb
date_as_string = "2008-10-17"
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['UTC'].parse(date_as_string)

# => Fri, 17 Oct 2008 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

And just to confirm that it worked..

```rb
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['UTC'].parse(date_as_string).class

# => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```